# how to create xml file in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm new to delphi and now I have to read create an xml. my code is the following:

unit writexml1;

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, xmldom, XMLIntf, StdCtrls, msxmldom, XMLDoc;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  rootName: String;
  childNode: String;
  attrChild: string;
  iXml: IDOMDocument;
  iRoot, iNode, iNode2, iChild, iAttribute: IDOMNode;
  XMLDoc: TXMLDocument;
begin
  XMLDoc.Active := False;
  XMLDoc.XML.Text := '';
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
  XMLDoc.SaveToFile('C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\zulfa.xml');
  iXml := XMLDoc.DOMDocument;
  iRoot := iXml.appendChild(iXml.createElement('xml'));
  iNode := iRoot.appendChild(iXml.createElement('test'));
  iNode.appendChild(iXml.createElement('test2'));
  iChild := iNode.appendChild(iXml.createElement('test3'));
  iChild.appendChild(iXml.createElement('Simple calue'));
  iNode.insertBefore(iXml.createElement('test4'), iChild);
  iNode2 := iNode.cloneNode(True);
  iRoot.appendChild(iNode2);
  iAttribute := iXml.createAttribute('color');
  iAttribute.nodeValue := 'red';
  iNode2.attributes.setNamedItem(iAttribute);
end;

end.
```

The problem is that while clicking the save button it shows the exception ,the exception is

> ```
> Project writexml1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation  with message 
> 'Access violation at address 004391B9 in module writexml.exe
> ```

Comment: Not related to your question, but why are you saving the content of XMLDoc to a file before you have any XML in it? Looks like your code will never result in a file with xml in it.

Answer (score 43):

your code looks a little complicated. I would suggest: forget `TXMLDocument` and  `IDOMDOCUMENT`, use `IXMLDOCUMENT` instead (the way to to use it ist almost the same then `TXmlDocument` but you dont need a component).

This code should demonstrate, how simple it is:

```
{...}
Var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; // looks better in Editor ;)
  RootNode := XML.AddChild('XML');
  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('Test');
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('Test2');
  CurNode.Text := 'Some Test 2 text';
  CurNode.Attributes['NewAttribute'] := 'Some Test2 Attribute Value';
  XMl.SaveToFile('C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\zulfa.xml');
{...}
```

This is how the resulting File would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML>
  <Test>
    <Test2 NewAttribute="Some Test2 Attribute Value">Some Test 2 text</Test2>
  </Test>
</XML>
```

I hope this helps

PS: This sample only needs the Units *XMLIntf* and *XmlDoc* so you can tidy your *uses* a little.

Answer (score 13):

You need to create the `XMLDoc` instance before you can use it:

```
XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(...);
try
  ... do stuff with XMLDOC
finally
  XMLDoc.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Be careful, though.  Dynamically creating a `TXMLDocument` with a `nil` Owner causes the `TXMLDocument` to act as an interface instead of an object.  Calling `Free()` on such an instance would be very bad.  If you want to use `Free()`, then you have to provide a non-`nil` Owner (in which case, the `Free()` is redundant since the Owner will free the `TXMLDocument` when the Owner is freed).  If you dynamically allocate a `TXMLDocument` with a `nil` Owner, you MUST assign it to a `IXMLDocument` variable, in which case use `NewXMLDocument()` instead of `TXMLDocument.Create(nil)`.

Comment: @remy I edit the answer to put in the constructor. But I've no idea what paramters to pass. Hence the .... The original answer was lacking detail.

Comment: Like any other component, `TXMLDocument`'s constructor takes a `TComponent` Owner as input.  If you specify a non-`nil` Owner, the Owner will take ownership of freeing the `TXMLDocument`. If you specify a `nil` Owner instead, then `TXMLDocument` will be ownerless and you are responsible for freeing it. But `TXMLDocument` is special in that latter case, as it does not act as a normal component when it has a `nil` Owner, it acts as a reference-counted interface instead, so you have to involve the reference counting system in order to free it properly.

Comment: @Remy: When I allocate XML document through NewXmlDocument(), how can I free instance when no longer need it?

Comment: @truthseeker: `NewXmlDocument()` returns a reference-counted `IXMLDocument` interface. It is freed automatically when there are no more references to it. You can let it go out of scope normally, or you can assign `nil` to it if you want to release it earlier.

Answer (score 13):

`SaveClick()` is declaring a local `XMLDoc` variable that is not assigning a valid `TXMLDocument` object before you use i.  You have a separate `XMLDocument1` component on your `TForm` but you are not using it.  Get rid of `XMLDoc` and use `XMLDocument1` instead.

Also, you are accessing the underlying `DOMDocument` directly.  Use the `TXMLDocument`'s own methods to build up the XML instead, do not drop down to the DOM layer unless you need to access vendor-specific functionality (which you do not in this situation).

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.SaveClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  iRoot, iNode, iNode2, iChild: IXMLNode; 
begin 
  XMLDocument1.Active := False;
  XMLDocument1.XML.Text := '';    
  XMLDocument1.Active := True;
  iRoot := XMLDocument.AddChild('xml'); 
  iNode := iRoot.AddChild('test'); 
  iNode.AddChild('test2'); 
  iChild := iNode.AddChild('test3'); 
  iChild.Text := 'Simple value'; 
  iNode.AddChild('test4', iNode.ChildNodes.IndexOf(iChild)); 
  iNode2 := iNode.CloneNode(True); 
  iRoot.ChildNodes.Add(iNode2); 
  iNode2.Attributes['color'] := 'red'; 
  XMLDocument1.SaveToFile('C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\zulfa.xml'); 
  XMLDocument1.Active := False;
end;
```

That produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <test>
    <test2 />     
    <test4 />
    <test3>Simple value</test3>
  </test>
  <test color="red">
    <test2 />     
    <test4 />
    <test3>Simple value</test3>
  </test>
</xml>
```

With that said, using `IXMLDocument` instead of `TXMLDocument`, like @knowledgestacker suggested, is usually a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library to manage and simplify working with XML files, you can check it [here](https://github.com/ArturoBL/Delphi/blob/main/IXMLData.pas).

Not sure of what structure you wanted to create but here's an example:

```
uses
  ..., IXMLData;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  d : TIXMLDoc;
  n1, n2 : IXMLNode;
begin
  d := TIXMLDoc.Create('XML');  //By default it uses utf-8 encoding but you specify other encoding as well
  n1 := d.addNode('Test');
  n2 := d.addNode(n1,'Test2');  //add node Test2 as child of node Test
  n2.Attributes['NewAttribute'] := 'Some Test2 Attribute Value';
  n2.Text := 'Some Test 2 text';
  d.SaveTofile('C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\zulfa.xml');  
end;
```

It will produce this XML:

```
<XML>
  <Test>
    <Test2 NewAttribute="Some Test2 Attribute Value">Some Test 2 text</Test2>
  </Test>
</XML>
```